# What is the view of guardian angels, of saints now in heaven, appearing on earth?

Tags: angels

In Acts 12:15 it is argued by some that at least one person may have thought Peter's angel might have talked like him. See the reference to Matthew 18:10 that speaks of guardian angels.

In Jewish tradition, guardian angels can take on human appearances.  For example, in another discussion (see below), quotes were given by Frank Luke. He argued that in among rabbinic writings, *Devarim Rabbah*, the rabbinic commentary on Deuteronomy, has an angel take on the appearance of Moses.

*Devarim Rabbah* 2:29, “Bar Kappara said: an angel descended in the likeness of Moses and made him flee and the Egyptians thought that the angel was Moses.”

He also points out that *Kohelet Rabbah*, the commentary on Ecclesiastes, has an angel appear looking like Solomon and sitting upon his throne. *Kohelet Rabbah* 2:4; “At that time an angel descended in the form of Solomon and sat upon his throne.”

What is the general Protestant Christian view of the guardian angels of saints, now in heaven, appearing on earth?

Have any Protestant writers argued a view that some of the alleged apparitions of saints in church history have been non human angels on assignment, taking on the appearance of saints for some specific mission or reason?

The quotes above came from and is prompted by the discussion [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/who-what-is-peters-angel), in which angels are described in Jewish history as sometimes appearing in the likeness of those that they are assigned to protect.

Comment: This is incorrect. The people in the house had not seen the person at the door. Only Rhoda saw Peter. Acts 12:16 makes it clear that only when the door was opened 'when they saw him' was the matter resolved. So the people saying 'it is his angel' did so for reasons _other than_ appearance.

Comment: Nigel, I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: The questions "what is the general Christian view" and "have any Protestant writers argued..." are very different questions!

Comment: @Alex, thanks for helping with a suggestion to fine tune the question.  I narrowed the scope of the question. I would appreciate it if those who have voted to close the question would clearly explain their reasoning for why it is not a clear question. The votes to close the question seems to me to just be a hyper-Protestant knee jerk reaction to a challenging question. Is asking for the opinions of theologians, not allowed in this format?

Comment: Related: [Which denominations believe in modern angelic interventions?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86115/50422)